# Dataloader - Upsert Contact and Relate to Account

Tags: data-loader, externalid, data-import

**How can I UPSERT Contact and relate it to the Account ?**

**Data Structure**

Supplier_ID__c (External Id on Account )

Supplier_AdminID__c (External ID on Contact)

Supplier_ID__c   (lookup field on Contact that looksup to Account)

**I am trying to UPSERT Contacts via Dataloader**

Structure of **CSV**

[image]

When I UPSERT CONTACTS via DataLoader, there is no field to map to AccountName.

In Salesforce when Creating Contact, AccountName is a lookup to Account.

**Steps in DataLoader**

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you choose in that step 2b that Account : Supplier_ID__c, its already telling dataloader to link that contact record to the account that has the value you give for Supplier_ID__c (it must be unique) You don't need the "AccountName" to match it

Comment: However, when the Contacts get inserted in Salesforce, the Account name is blank , and the Contact is not related to Account. i.e When i open an Account record , under related Contacts i dont see the contact that was inserted

Comment: Have you mapped that field later? (telling that the column SUPPLIER_ID__C should be used for the Account lookup? You need to tell which is the external Id field to use, and also which field of the file is used. I'm assuming that your first column matches the Supplier_Id__c of the Account Records you have in the system

Comment: @SergioAlcocer I was able to relate Contact to Account. Thank You !